# Saving non-associated data in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am writing an installer, and as such I need to save multiple types of data in different tables, even when not associated. Ideally I woud like to take care of this all at once. Here is a brief of what I have so far.

Here is my cake array in preparation for saving said data.

```
$initialData = array(
    array( 'Option' => array( 'name' => 'version', 'value' => '1.0.0', )),
    array( 'Option' => array( 'name' => 'non-version', 'value' => '1.0.2', )),
    array( 'User' => array( 'username' => 'skyler', 'password' => 'hi', )),
);
```

And I use the following to try and save it.

```
$this->Option->saveMany($initialData)
```

Which only saves the `Option` rows, not the `User` rows. Thoughts?

**NOTE: This is NOT associated data. Options and Users are not associated, but need to be saved at the same time.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$this->Option->saveMany` will work because you are saving multiple records for a single table. However, because the User is not associated to the Option, it does not know what to do with the data. You will need to call `$this->User->save($initialData)`.

If you expect to have multiple user records, you can call `$this->User->saveMany($initialData)`.

Be sure not to forget to call `$this->User->create()`.

Comment: So I essentially will need to use a separate $this->Model->save[Many] for each of the tables/models I have?

Comment: If they are not related... yes.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just ship an SQL script with my packages which creates and populates the database tables.

See [Multiple SQL query not executing in Cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924441/multiple-sql-query-not-executing-in-cakephp) for an example of how to read and execute the file in CakePHP.

Comment: Clearly the easiest answer. Problem is, what if my script has a table prefix? This needs to be dynamic, which is why I am looking to do this the CakePHP way.

Comment: You could use a macro in your raw sql file (e.g. [prefix]_my_table.foo) and replace it with the real prefix using str_replace() before you run the query.

Comment: Effective, but I definitely want to stick with CakePHP conventions. I plan to build out my data arrays, and use Model::save[Many] to populate my tables that way. Thanks for your help though.